# Exchange server reload Transport config from Active Directory

Tags: exchange

We have an Exchange 2013 in our domain (all roles in one server), only used as internal mail server.
Last week, i tried to update to CU14, but i've got an error :

> Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Clients.FormsAuthenticationMarkPathUnknownSetError:
>   An unexpected error occurred while modifying the forms authentication
>   settings for path /LM/W3SVC/1.  The error returned was 5506.

due to certificate or transport to internet not properly configured.
I exit the setup and decide to rollback (restore the entire VM with Veeam), but since done we can login (outlook or owa OK) but not receive new message (but all sent messages are stored in sent message folder).
In event viewer, i have a tons of 16028

> A forced configuration update for Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.TransportSettingsConfiguration has successfully completed.
>   Object details from last notification- based reload: . New details:

"update for" can be : Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.RemoteDomainTable, Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.TransportServerConfiguration, Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.ReceiveConnectorConfiguration, Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.X400AuthoritativeDomainTable, Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.AcceptedDomainTable, Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.TransportSettingsConfiguration

Restarting the server make no changes.
Note : the queue seems empty according to exchange toolbox.

I think the CU14 installer made change in active directory, and the restored Exchange read them.

I think i have to recreate send or receive connector, no ?
Actually i have default receive connectors (client frontend, client proxy, default frontend, default, outbound proxy frontend) and no send connector. I'm not sure if we have a send connector before CU14.

Thank you

Comment: I think you have better luck with server questions on our sister site, serverfault.